# S3 bucket CORS error for loading image via JS

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, cors, html2canvas

I have an s3 bucket setup with public files. This is the CORS config for this bucket -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/938934/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

In my html webpage, I am trying to access an image file from this bucket, and I am able to render image on my webpage via s3 bucket that -

```
<img src="bucketurl/abcd"/>
```

But, when I am trying to load that image via javascript, it is not loading and giving cors error. (this is a third party plugin code, which cannot bypass CORS. http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) -

```
var imageLoadHandler = function imageLoadHandler(supportsDataImages) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            return resolve(img);
        };
        //ios safari 10.3 taints canvas with data urls unless crossOrigin is set to anonymous
        if (!supportsDataImages || useCORS) {
            img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
        }

        img.onerror = reject;
        img.src = src;
        if (img.complete === true) {
            // Inline XML images may fail to parse, throwing an Error later on
            setTimeout(function () {
                resolve(img);
            }, 500);
        }
        if (_this4.options.imageTimeout) {
            var timeout = _this4.options.imageTimeout;
            setTimeout(function () {
                return reject( true ? 'Timed out (' + timeout + 'ms) fetching ' + src.substring(0, 256) : '');
            }, timeout);
        }
    });
};
```

This is the error -

```
Access to image at 'https://bucketurl/abcd' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I dont want to open resources from all origins. I just want to open resources from s3bucket. How and what change needs to be done for this.

Comment: I eventually ended up not using js to load the image. I decided to discard this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Your current CORS configuration allows `GET`, `HEAD`, and `POST` requests from all origins.

However, some browsers do send a preflight request <sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)</sup> to verify what HTTP requests are supported by a server.

The preflight request is a `OPTIONS` request and this is performed with specific headers. Your current configuration has only preflight requests with the Authorization header allowed 
This means that browsers like Google Chrome that send out a preflight request will fail on this note.

You should include entries for all headers sent in the preflight request as an allowed header in your CORS configuration. <sup>[2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#cors-eval-criteria)</sup>

I suggest restricting `CORSRule` to only origins that you've considered. Keep tweaking the rules till you come upon a restrictive policy that fits your application. <sup>[3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-cors)</sup>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/938934/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:8080</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>/replace with another preflight header/</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://html2canvas.herzen.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>OPTIONS</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>/replace with another preflight header/</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

You can view the response headers for the preflight request,  when you inspect it in the network tab of your browser.

You can also specify a wildcard to match allow all headers in the preflight request.

```
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
```

Comment: Thanks. When i am trying your solution, S3 is giving "Found unsupported HTTP method in CORS config. Unsupported method is OPTIONS" error.

Comment: I see, OPTIONS shouldn't be included but AllowedHeader entries should be configured for the list of all the headers included in the preflight request.